# How to insert a new key-value pair in an associative array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, associative-array

I've an associative array named `$classes_data` as follows:

```
Array
(
    [2] => Array
        (
            [class_id] => 2
            [class_name] => II
            [subjects] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 11 Engllish
                )

        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [class_id] => 3
            [class_name] => III
            [subjects] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Hidi
                    [1] => 11 Maths
                    [2] => 11 Science
                    [3] => 11 Engllish
                )

        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [class_id] => 4
            [class_name] => IV
            [subjects] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Physics
                )

        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [class_id] => 6
            [class_name] => VI
            [subjects] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Mathematics
                    [1] => dfadadadsagfasrsarasrarBiology
                )

        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [class_id] => 7
            [class_name] => VII
            [subjects] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Physics
                    [1] => Chemistry11
                    [2] => 11 Science
                )

        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [class_id] => 8
            [class_name] => VIII
            [subjects] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Hidi
                    [1] => 11 Engllish
                )

        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [class_id] => 9
            [class_name] => IX
            [subjects] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Mathematics
                    [1] => Hidi
                    [2] => 11 Science
                )

        )

)
```

The keys of array (viz. 2,3,4,6,7,8,9) are in this manner instead of 0,1,2,3,4,5,6 because I've used one function to rearrange these keys.

Now what I want to do is insert a new key `class_checked` and set its initial value as `0` (i.e.`class_checked =>"0"`).

I tried lot of tricks but couldn't get the desired array format. Can any one help me in this to get the desired array? Thanks in advance.

For your information the required array format for array `$classes_data` will be as follows:

```
 Array
    (
    [2] => Array
        (
            [class_id] => 2
            [class_name] => II
            [class_checked] => 0
            [subjects] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 11 Engllish
                )

        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [class_id] => 3
            [class_name] => III
            [class_checked] => 0
            [subjects] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Hidi
                    [1] => 11 Maths
                    [2] => 11 Science
                    [3] => 11 Engllish
                )

        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [class_id] => 4
            [class_name] => IV
            [class_checked] => 0
            [subjects] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Physics
                )

        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [class_id] => 6
            [class_name] => VI
            [class_checked] => 0
            [subjects] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Mathematics
                    [1] => dfadadadsagfasrsarasrarBiology
                )

        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [class_id] => 7
            [class_name] => VII
            [class_checked] => 0
            [subjects] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Physics
                    [1] => Chemistry11
                    [2] => 11 Science
                )

        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [class_id] => 8
            [class_name] => VIII
            [class_checked] => 0
            [subjects] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Hidi
                    [1] => 11 Engllish
                )

        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [class_id] => 9
            [class_name] => IX
            [class_checked] => 0
            [subjects] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Mathematics
                    [1] => Hidi
                    [2] => 11 Science
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: Show exactly what you have tried and what didn't work. What was the final result?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
foreach($classes_data as $key=>$value) {
    $classes_data[$key]['class_checked'] = 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Dharmesh Patel. This what I actually wanted. Your code really did the magic for me. Thank you once again for your valuable help.

Answer (score 4):

```
$array = array_map(function (array $i) { return $i + array('class_checked' => 0); }, $array);
```

Or:

```
foreach ($array as &$i) {
    $i['class_checked'] = 0;
}
unset($i);
```

Comment: Thanks deceze. your magic worked really fine for me. I got the desired array as per my requirement. Thank you once again for your great help.

Answer (score 0):

given your initial `$classes_data` you could do this:

```
foreach($classes_data as &$class) {
  $class['class_checked'] = 0;
}
```

now the array should be as you want it to be.